# Use libusb in a MacOS GUI application

Tags: swift, libusb, swiftpm

I'm trying to use libusb in a macOS application with GUI. But I always fail with "No such module 'CLibUSB'". I could use CLibUSB in a command line application, but cannot get it to work with a macOS GUI application.
What I did:

1. brew install libusb
2. $ mkdir Clibusb and  $ cd Clibusb/
3. make a system module

> $ swift package init --type system-module

4. Edit the package manifest Package.swift file to look like this

> // swift-tools-version:5.1
>
> ```
> import PackageDescription
>
>   let package = Package(
>     name: "Clibusb",
>     pkgConfig: "libusb-1.0",
>     providers: [
>       .brew(["libusb"])
>     ],
>     dependencies: [
>     // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on
>     // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
>     ]
>   )
> ```

5. Create a C shim header,

> echo '#include <libusb.h>' >shim.h

6. Write the module map module.modulemap

> ```
>   module CLibUSB [system] {
>   header "shim.h"
>   link "libusb-1.0"
>   export *
> }
> ```

7. Create a Git repository

> git init
> git add .
> git commit -m "Initial commit"

8. Make a client app

> ```
> mkdir LibUSBExample
> cd LibUSBExample
> swift package init --type executable
> ```

9. In the client app in main.swift. I import CLibUSB and do some tests - all that works

How can I use CLibUsb in a GUI Application?

Answer (score 0):

Download and copy **libusb** to your project folder from [github](https://github.com/libusb/libusb).

Drag **libusb.xcodeproj** in [libusb/Xcode](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/Xcode) into your project.

Create bridging header file :

```
#include "libusb.h"
```

---

### Update :

Add header search path :

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like I still can't build it. I copied libusb from the GitHub to my project and dragged libusb.xcodeproj to my project - looks like I can build libusb. Next I created the project-bridging-header.h and added the include. But it always gives me  "libusb.h file not found" when I try to build my project.

Comment: Have you added the header search path?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help!

The **bridging header** needs to contain **#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>**

I had to set **Header Search Path** = /usr/local/include and **Library Search Path** = /usr/local/lib correctly.

Under Frameworks, Library etc. I also had to set the library **libusb-1.0.a**
or **libusb-1.0.0.dylib**